# Which is the default Standard Deviation Formula

Tags: arithmetic, roots, average, standard-deviation, means

I have to implement a test from research paper which says:

As for testing criteria, standard deviation or min-to-90th
percentile ( ) of large packets (1500 B) can be
effectively used to find the existence of a wireless network.

Now, which standard deviation : population or sample is assumed to be the default ?

I guess the results will not be much different but still I want to implement the correct term.

Comment: So, will you use all possible packets, or only a random sample of packets?  That is: use sample standard deviation when your data is a sample, use population standard deviation when your data is the population.

Comment: @GEdgar I will use the first 200 packets. SO i guess I have to use population right ?

Comment: I would say use population s.d. only on the population.  (If the first 200 packets is not all the possible packets there can be, then it is not the population.)  Perhaps get better discussion of this in http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks a lot :).